# Incorporating vendor js files (from wrap bootstrap) into Rails 4

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, heroku

I'm struggling to understand how to incorporate vendor js assets into my Rails 4 application.

My app uses bootstrap. The vendor files include a js file, called npm.js. That file has the following in it:

```
// This file is autogenerated via the `commonjs` Grunt task. You can require() this file in a CommonJS environment.
require('../../js/transition.js')
require('../../js/alert.js')
require('../../js/button.js')
require('../../js/carousel.js')
require('../../js/collapse.js')
require('../../js/dropdown.js')
require('../../js/modal.js')
require('../../js/tooltip.js')
require('../../js/popover.js')
require('../../js/scrollspy.js')
require('../../js/tab.js')
require('../../js/affix.js')
```

In my app/assets/javascript folder, I have a file called application.js. In that file, I have:

```
//= require npm
```

In my console inspector, I can see an error with the incorporation of the npm file. The error message is:

```
npm.self-f66d504….js?body=1:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
```

I think it might be something to do with the ../.. references that are set out in the npm.js file.

Does anyone know how to adapt this for use in rails 4 (hosted on heroku)?

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

Those `require(...)` statements in your JS are in the CommonJS format (hence the comment at top) and are commonly used in Node.js but aren't supported in browser environments which is why you're getting that error in the inspector.

One option is to use Browserify with Grunt to link and compile each of those JS files into a single npm.js (though I'd recommend a different name) file. Are you already using browserify_rails, Grunt, or a similar tool to manage your JS files?

If you haven't worked with Grunt/Browserify, or if the above statement is unclear, it's probably best and simplest to just stick to the Rails asset pipeline:

So `application.js` would become:

```
//= require('<path>/js/transition.js')
//= require('<path>/js/alert.js')
//= require('<path>/js/button.js')
//= require('<path>/js/carousel.js')
// etc...
```

Instead of:

```
//= require npm
```

And this should generate equivalent JS to your sample above.

Finally, make sure `<path>` is included in your `config.assets.paths` config variable.